# A doubt regarding bijection of composite functions

Tags: functions, solution-verification

Let there be 2 functions *f* and *g* such that $f(x) $be a function from  $\mathbb{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$ and $g(x)$ be a function from $\mathbb{B} \rightarrow \mathbb{A}$ . If $f(x)$is injective(one-one mapping) and $g(x)$ be surjective(onto mapping). Then I was asked to comment on the nature of f(g(x)) and g(f(x)) being bijections or not.

 For f(g(x)) I was sure that since *f(x)* wasn't onto then fog cant be bijective. then we come to g(f(x)) here is where my doubt came in.
I assumed that let $\mathbb{B} $={k,l,m,n,o,p} and let $\mathbb{A}$={a,b,c} then let the mapping be something like this:
[image]

and so gof will come out to be
[image]

So I got the answer as we cant say anything about fog and gof being bijectives. But the answer given in my answer key(I was attempting this from an old maths book) was that gof is bijective i can't understand where did I make a mistake.

Comment: So sorry I accidently Put a C on the last set. in explaining gof ,corrected!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example $g(f(b))=a$, so it is a good proof that $g \circ f$ need not be bijectve.  The conditions give $\Bbb {|B| \ge |A|}$  If the sizes of $\Bbb {B \text { and } A}$ are equal and finite either the condition on $f$ or the one on $g$ is enough to show they are both bijections and  therefore the compositions are bijections as well.

Comment: yes thankyou so much and btw this "finite" condition is very very important as in case cardinality of the sets is infinite. then sometimes some elements are left to be mapped.